# Why has it suddenly asked me for a Captcha?

Tags: support

I'm logged in with a reputation of 20.2K. Why should it suddenly think I'm a bot?

Comment: What page were you on when it asked? Just curious.

Comment: I was replying to [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156349/back-to-vs-back-in/156351?noredirect=1#comment315880_156351) question.

Comment: Were you asked for a Captcha after clicking "submit answer"? Answers with too many links always and indiscriminately trigger a Captcha, because it's a common trait in spam posts.  Your rep wouldn't have changed it. || I saw the answer, and there are no links, so I think the only possible explanation would be it matching with other properties spam posts have. As to what those are, I have no idea.

Comment: It happens to me quite often when using my mobile browser (opera mini). I would just copy my answer, refresh the page, paste  and submit it.

Comment: This can happen if you start writing an answer and then, for whatever reason, you abandon it for maybe a couple of hours. When you come back to finish composing the answer, the system will ask if you are "human".  Actually, this always happens to me on EL&U when I'm too busy to finish an answer or question and I save it on a tab until the next day.